# How to compare elements of array with all rows DataTable in LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, datatable

I want to compare an element of an array with all rows in a DataTable.

My table is like this:

```
ID       Col B      Col C      Col D

2893     82         32          37
2893     43         90          73
3287     32         83          88
```

This is my code to do this:

```
string array;
array = Regex.Replace(array[2], @"\s+", " ").Replace("&nbsp;", "");


int[] index = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Select((rowF, idx) => new { rowF, idx })
             .Where(item => item.rowF.Field<String>("ID").Equals(array[0]) == true && 
             GetFirstCharacter(array) == GetFirstCharacter(item.rowF.Field<string>("Col B - Col C - Col D")))
             .Select(item => item.idx)
             .ToArray();

private static string GetFirstCharacter(string str)
{
    return string.Concat(str.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault());
}
```

You can see in LINQ code, at line:

`GetFirstCharacter(array) == GetFirstCharacter(item.rowF.Field<string>("Col B - Col C - Col D")))`

In the `Field<string>("it will get an array of all columns")`.

After I get `index[]` I will check the length of this array.

```
if (index.Length == 0)
      // some code to add new values to data table `dt`.
else
      // I got an index of rows in DataTable and replace new values to rows was exist.
```

I tried to create an array:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
   object[] value = { r["a0_2"], r["a0_3"], r["b0_2"], r["b0_3"], r["a1_2"], r["b1_2"], r["a1_3"], r["b1_3"], 
                    r["A3_2"], r["B3_2"], r["A3_3"], r["B3_3"], r["A4_2"], r["B4_2"], r["A4_3"], r["B4_3"] };
   for (int m = 0; m < value.Length; m++)
   {
        int[] index = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Select((rowF, idx) => new { rowF, idx })
             .Where(item => item.rowF.Field<String>("ID").Equals(array[0]) == true && 
             GetFirstCharacter(array) == GetFirstCharacter(item.rowF.Field<string>("Col B - Col C - Col D")))
             .Select(item => item.idx)
             .ToArray();
    }
 }
```

But it is not working.